# Was Buddha reincarnation of Agni?

Tags: avatars, rebirth, agni, buddha

Was buddha the reincarnation of vedic god agni?

āga means fire.

the pali way is *tathāgata*.
the jain way is *tathāgaya*.
blue_ego's way is *tathajāta*.

Comment: 3. There is a person who can remove the doubt of the people who go to him. He is the Buddha. See the excellent wisdom of the Buddhas! It is like a fire blazing at midnight. That wisdom gives beings bright knowledge and the eye of the Dhamma.

Comment: "Agni is the embodiment of the fire which consumes the offerings to the Hindu gods, so he is seen as the mediator between heaven and earth."

Comment: In a funeral hymn, Agni is asked to use his heat to warm the unborn (immortal) part of the deceased and to carry it to the world of the righteous. Agni carries men across calamities, as a ship over the sea.

Answer (score 3):

No, he was not.

In the Agni Purana, Agni himself says that Buddha is the avatar of Vishnu.

> ***Agni said:***
> 1] I am describing **the manifestation (of Viṣṇu) as Buddha**, by reading and hearing which one gets wealth. Once in the battle between devas and asuras, devas were defeated by the daityas (demons, sons of Diti).

([Agni Purana, Chapter 16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083104.html))

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146834/discussion-on-answer-by-cdr-was-buddha-reincarnation-of-agni); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.